# Material doesn't appears properly

Tags: materials

I have a material which looks pretty cool in the preview window however after applying it to an object, it isn't the same the material's preview is. How can I made my object to look same way the preview's object does? Sorry I am a new in Blender so I don't know how to google this problem. I tried find a solution but nothing found.

[image]

Here is [reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NfSuF5ce8-mH7Ce2eg7vbzJjMR2wdRAG/view?usp=sharing) to the file, the file is too big (80mb) for `blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com`

And here is [reference](https://www.blenderkit.com/asset-gallery-detail/0ba1e3ce-9ea4-4917-b94f-bad8e6f5b859/) to the original material in case it helps. A tried the author's recommendations (enable Experimental mode and Subdivision Surface) but that didn't help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You would have to share your material in blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com It can a problem just a scale or there seems to be a displacement that is not applied properly for real object. Thanks

Comment: vklidu, thank you for your reply. I just added the reference to the file in the original post, can you check please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material uses a displacement and will work only with Cycles rendering.

Also, the displacement scale is relatively low.

So, use Cycles and increase the displacement scale (check all parts in green below):

[image]

Additionally, you may need to add some subdivision to the object for a better rendering of this displacement.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you applied the image (diff or albedo) of the texture to your sphere, but you haven't connected your normal and height maps correctly.

You should look at your node setup in a shader window. The texture should have come with a normal map and a height map. Here's a typical setup: [image: TextureNodeSetup]

Comment: thank you for reply, however I didn't change default nodes. lemon's solution worked for me so question was resolved.